# TextBox Text doesn't update

Tags: c#, .net

I create TextBoxes dynamically, one for each column in a table(DataGridView). Every time I select a row in Table a text Box should have the value of the primaryKey row. First time it works, but after that the TextBox Text is not changing. But if I put a MessageBox to print the textbox.Text it printed it right, but not displayed it. When I tried the same thing with textboxes that aren't created dynamically I didn't have this problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns_number; i++)
{

    textBoxes[i] = new TextBox();
    labels[i] = new Label();
    labels[i].Text = childTable.Columns[i].Name;

    labels[i].Location = new Point(x_point - 100, y_point);
    textBoxes[i].Location = new Point(x_point, y_point);

    this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
    this.Controls.Add(textBoxes[i]);
    y_point = y_point + 30;
}

textBoxes[number].Text = selectedRow.Cells[vaterPrimaryKey].Value.ToString();

textBoxes[number].Refresh();
```

Comment: why do you need to create textboes and labels like this : `textBoxes[i] = new TextBox();` ?? i mean why use the `[i]` ?

Comment: for example if the table has 4 columns I have to create 4 textboxes but if the table has 3 I need just 3, and I have to know the order

Comment: Your for each statement creates the required amount of controls by itself ...and using `[i]` makes not much sense to me

Comment: but do you think that's why the text is not changing?

Comment: i am posting an answer , gimme a sec

Comment: ok, I am waiting :)

Comment: sorry , i was a bit busy , i am posting the answer now :)

Comment: wait, tell me this : How many textboxes and labels are you generating for each row/column ?

Comment: i am sorry , i misunderstood your code :( .... your code is almost right ... just a few fixes ... :)

Comment: for each column in the table I generate a textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code to find the textboxs and use them the way you want :

```
 string textboxName = "textboxes" + number.ToString
 TextBox mytextbox = this.Controls.Find(textboxName, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
 mytextbox.Text = selectedRow.Cells[vaterPrimaryKey].Value.ToString();
```